# Ansible-Merge two nested json files into single file using a key match

Tags: json, ansible

I am having two json and want to append one into another and save them in one file. I have done a set fact to read the values and put them in a variable using following:

```
- name: Set json combine to add new event
  set_fact:
     event_json_create: "{{ lookup('file', 'event_template.json') }}" 

- name: Set json combine to get the existing list of events
  set_fact:
     event_json_existing: "{{ lookup('file', 'notification.json') }}"
```

Now I want to append the event_json_create to event_json_existing.

The event_json_create looks like this:

```
"event_json_create": {
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [{
        "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:xyz"
    }]
        }
```

The event_json_existing looks like this:

```
 "event_json_existing": {
            "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [{
                    "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:******:function:abc"
                }],
    "TopicConfigurations": [{
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxx:crt"
    }]
        }
```

How can I append the two json in ansible ensuring that both json are under major group: LambdaFunctionConfigurations and retain the remaining content of TopicConfiguration  then I can write this into a json file. So the output I expect:

```
{
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
        {
           "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:xyz"
        },
        {
           "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:abc"
        }
       ],  
    "TopicConfigurations": [
     {
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxx:crt"
    }
    ]
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As an example of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) let's transform the question)

> Q: Given the dictionaries below

```
create:
  dict1:
    - key1: value1
```

```
existing:
  dict1:
    - key1: value2
  dict2:
    - key2: value3
```

get output

```
expected:
  dict1:
    - key1: value1
    - key1: value2
  dict2:
    - key2: value3
```

Write output to file in JSON

---

A: The tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        events: "{{ events|default({})|
                    combine({item: existing[item]|default([]) +
                                   create[item]|default([])}) }}"
      loop: "{{ (create.keys()|list + existing.keys()|list)|unique }}"
    - template:
        src: events.json.j2
        dest: events.json
```

with the template

```
shell> cat events.json.j2
{{ events|to_nice_json }}
```

give

```
shell> cat events.json
{
    "dict1": [
        {
            "key1": "value2"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    ],
    "dict2": [
        {
            "key2": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```